# Flash accessing native code

Tags: flash, dll

Is it possible to make a Flash embedded in a browser access a DLL, by making it signed or whatnot? I know that it's possible with Java Applets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. By far your best bet is going to be exposing whatever methods you need in your Class Library as web methods and letting Flash call them that way.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Air 3 Native Extensions: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html

Answer (score 0):

No, But.. you can compile native code into flash with [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/).

Comment: Alchemy definitely looks interesting. The only downside is that it's not production ready...and it looks like it takes your C/C++ and compiles it into ActionScript 3.0 (so anything with heavy dependencies is going to fail).

Comment: it actually compiles into byte-code for the flash VM, not into AS3. yes, dependencies would be an issue, so is performace since it is no-longer running natively.

Comment: Actually it does compile into a mix of AS3 and bytecode. Then, a specialized version of the flex compiler turns the mix into a SWC.